# My sql : join 2 tables on date

Tags: mysql, datetime, join

My mySql database contains some counting data tables of this type : date (DATETIME), data (INT).

I Would like create a view that addition data of 2 tables but I can't be sure that date of table1 are identic to date of table2.

For example :

Table1:

> 2013-01-01 10:00 / 100
>   2013-01-01 11:00 / 200
>   2013-01-01 12:00 / 300

Table2:

> 2013-01-01 11:00 / 500 
>   2013-01-01 12:00 / 600 
>   2013-01-01 13:00 / 700

With this 2 tables, I would like :
View1 = Table1+Table2

> 2013-01-01 10:00 / 100
>   2013-01-01 11:00 / 200+500=700
>   2013-01-01 12:00 / 300+600=900
>   2013-01-01 13:00 / 700

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: It would help to mock up your example in http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT `date`, SUM(data) AS sum
  FROM (
     SELECT `date`, data FROM table1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT `date`, data FROM table2

  ) AS u
  GROUP BY `date`
```

If your `table1` etc tables are very large you will probably get faster results by doing two things:

1. creating a compound index `(date, data)` on each table.
2. refactoring the query so each table is summarized before the `UNION ALL`.

The more efficient query might look like this.

```
  SELECT `date`, SUM(data) AS sum
    FROM (
            SELECT `date`, SUM(data) AS data FROM table1 GROUP BY `date`
         UNION ALL
            SELECT `date`, SUM(data) AS data FROM table2 GROUP BY `date`
         UNION ALL
            SELECT `date`, SUM(data) AS data FROM table3 GROUP BY `date`
         UNION ALL
            SELECT `date`, SUM(data) AS data FROM table4 GROUP BY `date`
          ) AS sums
   GROUP BY `date`
```

MySQL doesn't offer materialized views. That's Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
What do you think about performances if this tables have thousands of records.
Could I addition 10 tables with this view?
I thought use views maybe until groupment of 10 tables and if I have bigger groups, use some materialized views. What do you think about this?

Thank in advance.

Comment: @Gwenmeriaux, see my edit to my answer.